# How to write to WIN registry to assign values to right button?

Tags: vb.net

I hope you understand me.
I have little MD5 Check Sum app, and I want if i click on some file in the entire Windows OS, with right button, in the context menu there to be a button "Check MD5 Sum". Like when you install WinRar, the app assign values there for archive, and extracting. Thank you!
I'm Working in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a command to the Explorer context menu for all files add to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
```

as you would to a specific file type.

Comment: Okay, now how to check if my app is started from right click menu, or direct click?

Comment: If by "direct" you mean "double": there is a value to set the default command, but I doubt it will apply in the `*` key – and would be poor for users (who wants an MD5 calc when activating a Word document?)